# Monkey patching with Gorilla package applied to superclass method

Tags: python, monkeypatching

In Python I am using the [Gorilla](https://gorilla.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/) package for monkey patching the class hierarchy displayed in the image, which belongs to the [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/api.html) package.

[image: screenshot of class hierarchy]

I'm encountering problems when trying to patch method `fit` of abstract class `statsmodels.base.model.Model`, using annotation `@gorilla.patch(statsmodels.base.model.Model)` just before defining my own `fit(self)` function. If I do that and then call `fit` from e.g. class `statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS` the patch is not found when I call `gorilla.apply` and therefore, it is not applied. However if I specify `@gorilla.patch(statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionModel)` (a superclass that is closer to `OLS`) both in the annotation and in `gorilla.apply` and then call `fit` from `OLS`, the patch is found successfully.

I would like to patch any `fit` method that the user may call, disregarding the concrete subclass from which it has been called, hence I tried patching `fit` in the abstract common superclass. Is there a way to make it work for such general case? It is not for testing purposes.

Comment: Many models like OLS/RegressionModel define their own `fit` method and don't use the inherited method. So overriding the inherited method should not directly affect the method in the subclasses. Why would you want to do that? Most models have a model specific fit algorithm and it cannot be replace by a generic method.

Comment: One of the big advantages of the Python universe is that we don't monkey patch except in emergencies. That's one reason why Python thrives while programming languages where user culture is in favor of monkey patching (or where methods are automatically overridden across packages) don't survive.

Comment: Thanks Josef. I am trying to implement an autolog function able to log to file all (or at least, the most common) metrics of a fitted model, without the user explicitly calling it every time, just call autolog() with no params to enable it at the beginning of the user's program and that's it. The user code that uses statsmodels must remain unchanged. It should log all metrics of every model created by a call to fit from that moment, no matter which model or how many models. I've seen other people do the same quite easily with other packages (e.g. LightGBM) via monkey patching.

Comment: BTW if you please turn your first comment into an answer I'll be happy to accept it. I fixed it by recursively traversing the class hierarchy, checking class by class which ones actually override the fit method and then monkey-patch that class.